# Making New Table structure using pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

is it possible to change table structure in python by using pandas from this structure

| Label | Text |
| --- | --- |
| True | Car |
| True | Pool |
| Fake | Play |
| True | Music |

Into

| Text | True | Fake |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 1 | 0 |
| Pool | 1 | 0 |
| Play | 0 | 1 |
| Music | 1 | 0 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i've try to use pandas pivot_table, it doesn't work like i wanted to